# list the first few rows in Stata

Tags: stata

I have used R quite a bit and I know I can use `head(data[,"column"])` or `head(data)` to see the first few rows/cells of data.

How can I do that in Stata?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `list` command for this:

```
list column in 1/6
```

or

```
list in 1/6
```

If you have a look at `help list`, you will discover plenty of options to customize the display.

Comment: One of the reasons people ask questions on SO is because the included documentation is not clear.  So in this case help list might seem like a great idea, but the result is fairly incomprehensible.  The documentation is SATA is not stellar.